# Sorting numbers string with letter

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have strings such as

```
70x100 CM
70x140 CM
70x70 CM
72x120 CM
70x130x70 CM
70x75x70 CM
72x72 CM
```

When I want to sort in this order:

```
70x70 CM
70x75x70 CM
70x100 CM
70x130x70 CM
70x140 CM
72x72 CM
72x120 CM
```

this is my code:

```
ORDER BY CAST(CAST(eaov.value AS DECIMAL(3,0)) as UNSIGNED INTEGER), eaov.value
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Store the width, the depth, and the SI unit in separate columns.

Comment: ... integer type columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A minor mod to the answer by Strawberry. This is changing the 'cm' to a series of x0 to ensure that there are always 3 dimensions for the sort order

```
SELECT *
FROM eaov
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(eaov.value, ' CM', 'x0x0x0'), 'x', 1) as UNSIGNED INTEGER),
        CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(eaov.value, ' CM', 'x0x0x0'), 'x', 2), 'x', -1) as UNSIGNED INTEGER),
        CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(eaov.value, ' CM', 'x0x0x0'), 'x', 2), 'x', -1) as UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Performance will not be its strong point.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seriously advocating this as a solution - but as an interim measure (and easily adaptable to the purpose of normalising your design)...

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
  ORDER 
     BY substring_index(string,'x',1) + 0 
      , substring_index(substring_index(string,'x',-1),' ',1) + 0
```

Comment: doesn't work with this string

70x100 CM
70x140 CM
70x70 CM
72x120 CM
70x130x70 CM
70x75x70 CM
72x72 CM

Comment: @maurizio Aside from being useless, statements like "doesn't work" are completely unacceptable on SO.